# how to get the table and cell coordinates from pdf table using tabula?

Tags: tabula

I am planning to use tablula to extract tables from pdf file. I am able to see good results with the extraction part, however, I am using another library to extract the normal text from the table with font properties. I want to combine the output of tabula with this. This has to be done based on coordinates of the text or table cells. Is there any way in whcih I can get these details from tablua?